# IIS PHP JavaScript HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, iis

I am trying to send the request from ajax to php in IIS the small length data is being passed to php but when am trying to send the bigger data conol log says  `414 (Request-URI Too Long)` am running this site in IIS and i to have changed the IIS request Filtering settings[image: IIS setting] am not sure if i have to change any thing in PHP.

```
http://localhost/myfolder/attendence_submit.php?student%5B0%5D=ABHISHEK+T+K&Reg%5B0%5D=14KQC41001&schoolid%5B0%5D=FT001&section%5B0%5D=A&standard%5B0%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B0%5D=COM-21&date1%5B0%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B0%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B0%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B0%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B0%5D=Present&student%5B1%5D=ABHISHEK+T+R&Reg%5B1%5D=14KQC41002&schoolid%5B1%5D=FT001&section%5B1%5D=A&standard%5B1%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B1%5D=COM-21&date1%5B1%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B1%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B1%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B1%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B1%5D=Present&student%5B2%5D=AISHWARYA+K+R&Reg%5B2%5D=14KQC41003&schoolid%5B2%5D=FT001&section%5B2%5D=A&standard%5B2%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B2%5D=COM-21&date1%5B2%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B2%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B2%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B2%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B2%5D=Present&student%5B3%5D=AJEYA+C+S&Reg%5B3%5D=14KQC41004&schoolid%5B3%5D=FT001&section%5B3%5D=A&standard%5B3%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B3%5D=COM-21&date1%5B3%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B3%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B3%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B3%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B3%5D=Present&student%5B4%5D=AMRUTHA+K+N&Reg%5B4%5D=14KQC41006&schoolid%5B4%5D=FT001&section%5B4%5D=A&standard%5B4%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B4%5D=COM-21&date1%5B4%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B4%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B4%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B4%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B4%5D=Present&student%5B5%5D=AMUNA&Reg%5B5%5D=14KQC41007&schoolid%5B5%5D=FT001&section%5B5%5D=A&standard%5B5%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B5%5D=COM-21&date1%5B5%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B5%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B5%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B5%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B5%5D=Present&student%5B6%5D=ANILKUMAR+B+Y&Reg%5B6%5D=14KQC41008&schoolid%5B6%5D=FT001&section%5B6%5D=A&standard%5B6%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B6%5D=COM-21&date1%5B6%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B6%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B6%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B6%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B6%5D=Present&student%5B7%5D=ANUSHREE+S&Reg%5B7%5D=14KQC41010&schoolid%5B7%5D=FT001&section%5B7%5D=A&standard%5B7%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B7%5D=COM-21&date1%5B7%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B7%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B7%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B7%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B7%5D=Present&student%5B8%5D=ANUTHA+H+P&Reg%5B8%5D=14KQC41011&schoolid%5B8%5D=FT001&section%5B8%5D=A&standard%5B8%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B8%5D=COM-21&date1%5B8%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B8%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B8%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B8%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B8%5D=Present&student%5B9%5D=ARPITHA++HN+&Reg%5B9%5D=14KQC41012&schoolid%5B9%5D=FT001&section%5B9%5D=A&standard%5B9%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B9%5D=COM-21&date1%5B9%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B9%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B9%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B9%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B9%5D=Present&student%5B10%5D=ARUNA+D+R&Reg%5B10%5D=14KQC41013&schoolid%5B10%5D=FT001&section%5B10%5D=A&standard%5B10%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B10%5D=COM-21&date1%5B10%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B10%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B10%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B10%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B10%5D=Present&student%5B11%5D=ARUNKUMAR+M+C&Reg%5B11%5D=14KQC41015&schoolid%5B11%5D=FT001&section%5B11%5D=A&standard%5B11%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B11%5D=COM-21&date1%5B11%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B11%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B11%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B11%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B11%5D=Present&student%5B12%5D=ARUNKUMAR+V+M&Reg%5B12%5D=14KQC41016&schoolid%5B12%5D=FT001&section%5B12%5D=A&standard%5B12%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B12%5D=COM-21&date1%5B12%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B12%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B12%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B12%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B12%5D=Present&student%5B13%5D=ASHWINI+A+L&Reg%5B13%5D=14KQC41018&schoolid%5B13%5D=FT001&section%5B13%5D=A&standard%5B13%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B13%5D=COM-21&date1%5B13%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B13%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B13%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B13%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B13%5D=Present&student%5B14%5D=ASHWINI+G&Reg%5B14%5D=14KQC41019&schoolid%5B14%5D=FT001&section%5B14%5D=A&standard%5B14%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B14%5D=COM-21&date1%5B14%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B14%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B14%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B14%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B14%5D=Present&student%5B15%5D=ASHWINI+P&Reg%5B15%5D=14KQC41020&schoolid%5B15%5D=FT001&section%5B15%5D=A&standard%5B15%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B15%5D=COM-21&date1%5B15%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B15%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B15%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B15%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B15%5D=Present&student%5B16%5D=BABY+T+P&Reg%5B16%5D=14KQC41022&schoolid%5B16%5D=FT001&section%5B16%5D=A&standard%5B16%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B16%5D=COM-21&date1%5B16%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B16%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B16%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B16%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B16%5D=Present&student%5B17%5D=BASAVARAJU+M+C&Reg%5B17%5D=14KQC41023&schoolid%5B17%5D=FT001&section%5B17%5D=A&standard%5B17%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B17%5D=COM-21&date1%5B17%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B17%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B17%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B17%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B17%5D=Present&student%5B18%5D=BHARATH+B+M&Reg%5B18%5D=14KQC41024&schoolid%5B18%5D=FT001&section%5B18%5D=A&standard%5B18%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B18%5D=COM-21&date1%5B18%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B18%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B18%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B18%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B18%5D=Present&student%5B19%5D=BHAVYA+C+N&Reg%5B19%5D=14KQC41026&schoolid%5B19%5D=FT001&section%5B19%5D=A&standard%5B19%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B19%5D=COM-21&date1%5B19%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B19%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B19%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B19%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B19%5D=Present&student%5B20%5D=BINDUSHREE+A&Reg%5B20%5D=14KQC41027&schoolid%5B20%5D=FT001&section%5B20%5D=A&standard%5B20%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B20%5D=COM-21&date1%5B20%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B20%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B20%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B20%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B20%5D=Present&student%5B21%5D=CHAITHRA+A+M&Reg%5B21%5D=14KQC41028&schoolid%5B21%5D=FT001&section%5B21%5D=A&standard%5B21%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B21%5D=COM-21&date1%5B21%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B21%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B21%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B21%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B21%5D=Present&student%5B22%5D=CHAITHRA+B+S&Reg%5B22%5D=14KQC41029&schoolid%5B22%5D=FT001&section%5B22%5D=A&standard%5B22%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B22%5D=COM-21&date1%5B22%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B22%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B22%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B22%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B22%5D=Present&student%5B23%5D=CHAITHRA+K+M&Reg%5B23%5D=14KQC41030&schoolid%5B23%5D=FT001&section%5B23%5D=A&standard%5B23%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B23%5D=COM-21&date1%5B23%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B23%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B23%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B23%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B23%5D=Present&student%5B24%5D=CHANDAN+R&Reg%5B24%5D=14KQC41031&schoolid%5B24%5D=FT001&section%5B24%5D=A&standard%5B24%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B24%5D=COM-21&date1%5B24%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B24%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B24%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B24%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B24%5D=Present&student%5B25%5D=CHANDANI+H+M&Reg%5B25%5D=14KQC41032&schoolid%5B25%5D=FT001&section%5B25%5D=A&standard%5B25%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B25%5D=COM-21&date1%5B25%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B25%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B25%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B25%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B25%5D=Present&student%5B26%5D=CHANDHRAKUMAR+S&Reg%5B26%5D=14KQC41033&schoolid%5B26%5D=FT001&section%5B26%5D=A&standard%5B26%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B26%5D=COM-21&date1%5B26%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B26%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B26%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B26%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B26%5D=Present&student%5B27%5D=CHANDRU+D&Reg%5B27%5D=14KQC41035&schoolid%5B27%5D=FT001&section%5B27%5D=A&standard%5B27%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B27%5D=COM-21&date1%5B27%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B27%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B27%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B27%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B27%5D=Present&student%5B28%5D=CHARAN+H+R&Reg%5B28%5D=14KQC41036&schoolid%5B28%5D=FT001&section%5B28%5D=A&standard%5B28%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B28%5D=COM-21&date1%5B28%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B28%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B28%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B28%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B28%5D=Present&student%5B29%5D=CHARAN+K&Reg%5B29%5D=14KQC41037&schoolid%5B29%5D=FT001&section%5B29%5D=A&standard%5B29%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B29%5D=COM-21&date1%5B29%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B29%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B29%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B29%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B29%5D=Present&student%5B30%5D=CHETHAN++KUMAR+H+P&Reg%5B30%5D=14KQC41038&schoolid%5B30%5D=FT001&section%5B30%5D=A&standard%5B30%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B30%5D=COM-21&date1%5B30%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B30%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B30%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B30%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B30%5D=Present&student%5B31%5D=CHETHAN+S&Reg%5B31%5D=14KQC41039&schoolid%5B31%5D=FT001&section%5B31%5D=A&standard%5B31%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B31%5D=COM-21&date1%5B31%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B31%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B31%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B31%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B31%5D=Present&student%5B32%5D=CHIRANJEEVI+GOWDA+GM&Reg%5B32%5D=14KQC41040&schoolid%5B32%5D=FT001&section%5B32%5D=A&standard%5B32%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B32%5D=COM-21&date1%5B32%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B32%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B32%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B32%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B32%5D=Present&student%5B33%5D=DEEKSHITHKUMAR+S&Reg%5B33%5D=14KQC41041&schoolid%5B33%5D=FT001&section%5B33%5D=A&standard%5B33%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B33%5D=COM-21&date1%5B33%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B33%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B33%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B33%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B33%5D=Present&student%5B34%5D=DEEPA+A+V&Reg%5B34%5D=14KQC41042&schoolid%5B34%5D=FT001&section%5B34%5D=A&standard%5B34%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B34%5D=COM-21&date1%5B34%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B34%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B34%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B34%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B34%5D=Present&student%5B35%5D=DILEEPKUMAR+K+S&Reg%5B35%5D=14KQC41045&schoolid%5B35%5D=FT001&section%5B35%5D=A&standard%5B35%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B35%5D=COM-21&date1%5B35%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B35%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B35%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B35%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B35%5D=Present&student%5B36%5D=DINESH+G&Reg%5B36%5D=14KQC41046&schoolid%5B36%5D=FT001&section%5B36%5D=A&standard%5B36%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B36%5D=COM-21&date1%5B36%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B36%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B36%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B36%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B36%5D=Present&student%5B37%5D=DIVYA+N&Reg%5B37%5D=14KQC41047&schoolid%5B37%5D=FT001&section%5B37%5D=A&standard%5B37%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B37%5D=COM-21&date1%5B37%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B37%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B37%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B37%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B37%5D=Present&student%5B38%5D=DIVYA+R&Reg%5B38%5D=14KQC41048&schoolid%5B38%5D=FT001&section%5B38%5D=A&standard%5B38%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B38%5D=COM-21&date1%5B38%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B38%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B38%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B38%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B38%5D=Present&student%5B39%5D=DIVYA+SHANKARI+N&Reg%5B39%5D=14KQC41049&schoolid%5B39%5D=FT001&section%5B39%5D=A&standard%5B39%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B39%5D=COM-21&date1%5B39%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B39%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B39%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B39%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B39%5D=Present&student%5B40%5D=DURGAIAH+T+R&Reg%5B40%5D=14KQC41050&schoolid%5B40%5D=FT001&section%5B40%5D=A&standard%5B40%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B40%5D=COM-21&date1%5B40%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B40%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B40%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B40%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B40%5D=Present&student%5B41%5D=DURGAPRASAD+V&Reg%5B41%5D=14KQC41051&schoolid%5B41%5D=FT001&section%5B41%5D=A&standard%5B41%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B41%5D=COM-21&date1%5B41%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B41%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B41%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B41%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B41%5D=Present&student%5B42%5D=ELWIN+VANANCEANTHONY+GONSALVES&Reg%5B42%5D=14KQC41053&schoolid%5B42%5D=FT001&section%5B42%5D=A&standard%5B42%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B42%5D=COM-21&date1%5B42%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B42%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B42%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B42%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B42%5D=Present&student%5B43%5D=FELIX+LOURDU+SWAMY&Reg%5B43%5D=14KQC41054&schoolid%5B43%5D=FT001&section%5B43%5D=A&standard%5B43%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B43%5D=COM-21&date1%5B43%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B43%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B43%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B43%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B43%5D=Present&student%5B44%5D=GEETHA+SHREE+J&Reg%5B44%5D=14KQC41056&schoolid%5B44%5D=FT001&section%5B44%5D=A&standard%5B44%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B44%5D=COM-21&date1%5B44%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B44%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B44%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B44%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B44%5D=Present&student%5B45%5D=GIRISHA+B+S&Reg%5B45%5D=14KQC41058&schoolid%5B45%5D=FT001&section%5B45%5D=A&standard%5B45%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B45%5D=COM-21&date1%5B45%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B45%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B45%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B45%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B45%5D=Present&student%5B46%5D=GOVINDARAJU+S+V&Reg%5B46%5D=14KQC41059&schoolid%5B46%5D=FT001&section%5B46%5D=A&standard%5B46%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B46%5D=COM-21&date1%5B46%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B46%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B46%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B46%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B46%5D=Present&student%5B47%5D=GOWRAMMA+G&Reg%5B47%5D=14KQC41060&schoolid%5B47%5D=FT001&section%5B47%5D=A&standard%5B47%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B47%5D=COM-21&date1%5B47%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B47%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B47%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B47%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B47%5D=Present&student%5B48%5D=GOWTHAM+T+S&Reg%5B48%5D=14KQC41061&schoolid%5B48%5D=FT001&section%5B48%5D=A&standard%5B48%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B48%5D=COM-21&date1%5B48%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B48%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B48%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B48%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B48%5D=Present&student%5B49%5D=HEMALATHA+R&Reg%5B49%5D=14KQC41063&schoolid%5B49%5D=FT001&section%5B49%5D=A&standard%5B49%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B49%5D=COM-21&date1%5B49%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B49%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B49%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B49%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B49%5D=Present&student%5B50%5D=HEMANTH+KUMAR+K&Reg%5B50%5D=14KQC41064&schoolid%5B50%5D=FT001&section%5B50%5D=A&standard%5B50%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B50%5D=COM-21&date1%5B50%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B50%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B50%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B50%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B50%5D=Present&student%5B51%5D=HEMANTHA+B+T&Reg%5B51%5D=14KQC41065&schoolid%5B51%5D=FT001&section%5B51%5D=A&standard%5B51%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B51%5D=COM-21&date1%5B51%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B51%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B51%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B51%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B51%5D=Present&student%5B52%5D=HEMAVATHI+S+R&Reg%5B52%5D=14KQC41066&schoolid%5B52%5D=FT001&section%5B52%5D=A&standard%5B52%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B52%5D=COM-21&date1%5B52%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B52%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B52%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B52%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B52%5D=Present&student%5B53%5D=IRSHAD&Reg%5B53%5D=14KQC41067&schoolid%5B53%5D=FT001&section%5B53%5D=A&standard%5B53%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B53%5D=COM-21&date1%5B53%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B53%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B53%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B53%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B53%5D=Present&student%5B54%5D=JAYASHEELA+K&Reg%5B54%5D=14KQC41068&schoolid%5B54%5D=FT001&section%5B54%5D=A&standard%5B54%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B54%5D=COM-21&date1%5B54%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B54%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B54%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B54%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B54%5D=Present&student%5B55%5D=KAMALAKSHI+D+S&Reg%5B55%5D=14KQC41070&schoolid%5B55%5D=FT001&section%5B55%5D=A&standard%5B55%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B55%5D=COM-21&date1%5B55%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B55%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B55%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B55%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B55%5D=Present&student%5B56%5D=KARANRAJ+J&Reg%5B56%5D=14KQC41071&schoolid%5B56%5D=FT001&section%5B56%5D=A&standard%5B56%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B56%5D=COM-21&date1%5B56%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B56%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B56%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B56%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B56%5D=Present&student%5B57%5D=KARTHIK+H+P&Reg%5B57%5D=14KQC41072&schoolid%5B57%5D=FT001&section%5B57%5D=A&standard%5B57%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B57%5D=COM-21&date1%5B57%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B57%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B57%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B57%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B57%5D=Present&student%5B58%5D=KAVYA+H+S&Reg%5B58%5D=14KQC41073&schoolid%5B58%5D=FT001&section%5B58%5D=A&standard%5B58%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B58%5D=COM-21&date1%5B58%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B58%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B58%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B58%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B58%5D=Present&student%5B59%5D=KAVYASHREE+V&Reg%5B59%5D=14KQC41074&schoolid%5B59%5D=FT001&section%5B59%5D=A&standard%5B59%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B59%5D=COM-21&date1%5B59%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B59%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B59%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B59%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B59%5D=Present&student%5B60%5D=KEERTHIGOWDA+D+S&Reg%5B60%5D=14KQC41076&schoolid%5B60%5D=FT001&section%5B60%5D=A&standard%5B60%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B60%5D=COM-21&date1%5B60%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B60%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B60%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B60%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B60%5D=Present&student%5B61%5D=KIRAN+K+R&Reg%5B61%5D=14KQC41077&schoolid%5B61%5D=FT001&section%5B61%5D=A&standard%5B61%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B61%5D=COM-21&date1%5B61%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B61%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B61%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B61%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B61%5D=Present&student%5B62%5D=KIRAN+KUMAR+A+&Reg%5B62%5D=14KQC41078&schoolid%5B62%5D=FT001&section%5B62%5D=A&standard%5B62%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B62%5D=COM-21&date1%5B62%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B62%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B62%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B62%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B62%5D=Present&student%5B63%5D=KOWSHIK+CK&Reg%5B63%5D=14KQC41079&schoolid%5B63%5D=FT001&section%5B63%5D=A&standard%5B63%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B63%5D=COM-21&date1%5B63%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B63%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B63%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B63%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B63%5D=Present&student%5B64%5D=LAKSHMI+H+S&Reg%5B64%5D=14KQC41080&schoolid%5B64%5D=FT001&section%5B64%5D=A&standard%5B64%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B64%5D=COM-21&date1%5B64%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B64%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B64%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B64%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B64%5D=Present&student%5B65%5D=LAKSHMI+V&Reg%5B65%5D=14KQC41081&schoolid%5B65%5D=FT001&section%5B65%5D=A&standard%5B65%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B65%5D=COM-21&date1%5B65%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B65%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B65%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B65%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B65%5D=Present&student%5B66%5D=LAVANYA+D+R&Reg%5B66%5D=14KQC41082&schoolid%5B66%5D=FT001&section%5B66%5D=A&standard%5B66%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B66%5D=COM-21&date1%5B66%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B66%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B66%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B66%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B66%5D=Present&student%5B67%5D=LAVANYA+P&Reg%5B67%5D=14KQC41083&schoolid%5B67%5D=FT001&section%5B67%5D=A&standard%5B67%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B67%5D=COM-21&date1%5B67%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B67%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B67%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B67%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B67%5D=Present&student%5B68%5D=LAVANYA+S&Reg%5B68%5D=14KQC41084&schoolid%5B68%5D=FT001&section%5B68%5D=A&standard%5B68%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B68%5D=COM-21&date1%5B68%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B68%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B68%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B68%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B68%5D=Present&student%5B69%5D=LIKHITHA+K+S&Reg%5B69%5D=14KQC41085&schoolid%5B69%5D=FT001&section%5B69%5D=A&standard%5B69%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B69%5D=COM-21&date1%5B69%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B69%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B69%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B69%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B69%5D=Present&student%5B70%5D=LIKITH+H+S&Reg%5B70%5D=14KQC41086&schoolid%5B70%5D=FT001&section%5B70%5D=A&standard%5B70%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B70%5D=COM-21&date1%5B70%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B70%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B70%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B70%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B70%5D=Present&student%5B71%5D=LOKESH+K+M&Reg%5B71%5D=14KQC41087&schoolid%5B71%5D=FT001&section%5B71%5D=A&standard%5B71%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B71%5D=COM-21&date1%5B71%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B71%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B71%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B71%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B71%5D=Present&student%5B72%5D=LOKESH+V&Reg%5B72%5D=14KQC41088&schoolid%5B72%5D=FT001&section%5B72%5D=A&standard%5B72%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B72%5D=COM-21&date1%5B72%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B72%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B72%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B72%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B72%5D=Present&student%5B73%5D=MADESH+K+V&Reg%5B73%5D=14KQC41089&schoolid%5B73%5D=FT001&section%5B73%5D=A&standard%5B73%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B73%5D=COM-21&date1%5B73%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B73%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B73%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B73%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B73%5D=Present&student%5B74%5D=MADHU+H+S&Reg%5B74%5D=14KQC41090&schoolid%5B74%5D=FT001&section%5B74%5D=A&standard%5B74%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B74%5D=COM-21&date1%5B74%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B74%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B74%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B74%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B74%5D=Present&student%5B75%5D=MADHUSHREE+G&Reg%5B75%5D=14KQC41091&schoolid%5B75%5D=FT001&section%5B75%5D=A&standard%5B75%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B75%5D=COM-21&date1%5B75%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B75%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B75%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B75%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B75%5D=Present&student%5B76%5D=MADHUSUDANGOWDA+&Reg%5B76%5D=14KQC41092&schoolid%5B76%5D=FT001&section%5B76%5D=A&standard%5B76%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B76%5D=COM-21&date1%5B76%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B76%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B76%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B76%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B76%5D=Absent&student%5B77%5D=MALLESH+N&Reg%5B77%5D=14KQC41094&schoolid%5B77%5D=FT001&section%5B77%5D=A&standard%5B77%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B77%5D=COM-21&date1%5B77%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B77%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B77%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B77%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B77%5D=Absent&student%5B78%5D=MANJUNATHA+H+E&Reg%5B78%5D=14KQC41095&schoolid%5B78%5D=FT001&section%5B78%5D=A&standard%5B78%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B78%5D=COM-21&date1%5B78%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B78%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B78%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B78%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B78%5D=Absent&student%5B79%5D=MANJUNATHA+S&Reg%5B79%5D=14KQC41096&schoolid%5B79%5D=FT001&section%5B79%5D=A&standard%5B79%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B79%5D=COM-21&date1%5B79%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B79%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B79%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B79%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B79%5D=Absent&student%5B80%5D=MANJUSHREE+D+C&Reg%5B80%5D=14KQC41097&schoolid%5B80%5D=FT001&section%5B80%5D=A&standard%5B80%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B80%5D=COM-21&date1%5B80%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B80%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B80%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B80%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B80%5D=Absent&student%5B81%5D=MANU+H+K&Reg%5B81%5D=14KQC41098&schoolid%5B81%5D=FT001&section%5B81%5D=A&standard%5B81%5D=II+BCOM&Subject%5B81%5D=COM-21&date1%5B81%5D=16-01-05+00%3A00%3A00&UserType%5B81%5D=STUDENT&Userid%5B81%5D=admin&date_user_submitted%5B81%5D=2016-01-05++11%3A55%3A44+am&present%5B81%5D=Absent
```

Method am using is jquery Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/myfolder/attendence_submit.php',
        data: $('#mySpan4').serialize(), 
        success: function(data) {


            tosmsphpdate ();
        }
    });
```

My PHP

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "0000";

$dbname = "s_cool_age";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// ** insert data in to data base ** //
$sql = "INSERT INTO attendance_master (StudentFirstName,AttendanceStatus,StudentRegID,SchoolID,Section,Standard,Subjects,AttendanceDate,UserType,Attendence_taken_by,Attendence_taken_date) VALUES ";
// **hear the data or is calculated using student as a string the number of student names are passed the same number of data is inserted in to data base ** //
foreach($_GET['student']  as $i=>$student) {

    // ** so the data is inserted in to data base   ** //
    $sql .= sprintf("%s ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
    , ($i==0 ? '' : ',')  
    // **  data from Ajax   ** //
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['student'][$i]))
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['present'][$i]))
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['Reg'][$i]))
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['schoolid'][$i]))
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['section'][$i]))
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['standard'][$i]))
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['Subject'][$i]))
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['date1'][$i]))
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['UserType'][$i]))
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['Userid'][$i]))
    , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_GET['date_user_submitted'][$i]))

    );
}
// ** on success full function   ** //
if ($conn->query($sql)) {
    // **can do any thing to recognise if the data is inserted if this gives the out put then the data is shorly inserted in to data base  ** //
}
```

Comment: Different browsers have different limit for query string length..

Comment: How to check that and am doing this as a mobile app

Comment: Why are you passing data in your query string??...query string should be small and simple as possible..This will help you http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Comment: Which method are using for this, for passing the request ? I would suggest to use post method

Comment: ajax `
 $.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/myfolder/attendence_submit.php',
  data: $('#mySpan4').serialize(), 
  success: function(data) {
   
   
   tosmsphpdate ();
  }
 });`

Comment: am getting 414 error  `414 (Request-URI Too Long)` can any one help me solving this error am not sure i googled alot am not getting how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must definitely be a post request, not a get request.
The choise of GET/POST for normal form processing, and for ajax, is the same.

GET should be used: only to read data from a server.
SQL queries are 'SELECT' queries.

POST is to change the data on the server.  INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE data should always be done with POST

note: there is a limit to the length of a URL.  That's what gives you the error.  So just using POST should solve the problem. (but even if the problem isn't solved by this alone, still do it)

---

This works.  I skipped the database part, since I don't have that table.  But I think it should work.

attendence_submit.php

```
<?php
// TODO: put your own connection data back
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "stackoverflow";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {  // process POST data
    $sql = "INSERT INTO attendance_master (StudentFirstName,AttendanceStatus,StudentRegID,SchoolID,Section,Standard,Subjects,AttendanceDate,UserType,Attendence_taken_by,Attendence_taken_date) VALUES ";
    foreach($_POST['student']  as $i=>$student) {
        $sql .= sprintf("%s ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
            , ($i==0 ? '' : ',')
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['student'][$i]))
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['present'][$i]))
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['Reg'][$i]))
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['schoolid'][$i]))
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['section'][$i]))
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['standard'][$i]))
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['Subject'][$i]))
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['date1'][$i]))
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['UserType'][$i]))
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['Userid'][$i]))
            , mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['date_user_submitted'][$i])
            ));
    }
    // TODO: do database stuff here

    // as a test we return the sql string to Ajax
    echo $sql;
    exit;
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="student[]"> student<br/>
      <input type="text" name="present[]"> present<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Reg[]"> Reg<br/>
      <input type="text" name="schoolid[]"> schoolid<br/>
      <input type="text" name="section[]"> section<br/>
      <input type="text" name="standard[]"> standard<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Subject[]"> Subject<br/>
      <input type="text" name="date1[]"> date1<br/>
      <input type="text" name="schdate1oolid[]"> date1<br/>
      <input type="text" name="UserType[]"> UserType<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Userid[]"> Userid<br/>
      <input type="text" name="date_user_submitted[]"> date_user_submitted<br/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="student[]"> student<br/>
      <input type="text" name="present[]"> present<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Reg[]"> Reg<br/>
      <input type="text" name="schoolid[]"> schoolid<br/>
      <input type="text" name="section[]"> section<br/>
      <input type="text" name="standard[]"> standard<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Subject[]"> Subject<br/>
      <input type="text" name="date1[]"> date1<br/>
      <input type="text" name="schdate1oolid[]"> date1<br/>
      <input type="text" name="UserType[]"> UserType<br/>
      <input type="text" name="Userid[]"> Userid<br/>
      <input type="text" name="date_user_submitted[]"> date_user_submitted<br/>
    </fieldset>   
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="log"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
           $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'attendence_submit.php',   // you should not use absolute addresses, with http:// . only relative paths
              data: $('#myform').serialize(),
              success: function(data) {
                  // log $sql string
                  $('#log').html(data);
              }
           });
           // prevents the form from really submitting through the normal way
           e.preventDefault();
           return false;
       })
    });
</script>
```

---

My Ajax return is echo $sql;

You could use something more interesting.

like

```
<?php
if ($conn->query($sql)) {
  echo 1;
}
else  {
  echo 0;
}
?>
```

Then you can use that 1/0 (of use 'success'/'error') in the further processing in javascript.

like

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data == 1) {
    // success!
    // empty the form
    $('#myform').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");  
    //  ...      
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem.  by the way, use the latest code you see. I updated my answer a few times

Comment: Hi need your help the post is working fine but it inserts only 97 rows

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/myfolder/attendence_submit.php',
            data: $('#mySpan4').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json' ,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {


                tosmsphpdate ();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but wat about the php where it has get

Comment: again it is giving me  same error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Long)`